# Where's the right place to initialize a Sequel DB connection using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sequel, unixodbc

This is a follow up to [How to use unixODBC SSO connection to Snowflake with Rails using externalbrowser authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75457107/21217341).

We found that on Linux (`AlmaLinux 9` and `Ubuntu`) during application boot up `Rails 7.0.4` doesn't wait for socket accept to finish a SAML authentication, but immediately returns `-1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)`. In my application AFAIK need to do this authentication during initialization. So my application doesn't work.

Putting the connection command in a place that gets executed after initialization the authentication process works fine. But then the model initialization doesn't work correctly as I don't use `application_record` but `Sequel::Model` like:

```
class Generalnote < Sequel::Model(DB[:spectra__notes__general_metadata])
    self.set_primary_key :lake_batch_id
end
```

Code (incl. authentication during initialization) works fine under Windows, but for production it should run on a Linux system.

Is there a better place to do `DB = Sequel.connect(...` than `application.rb` to avoid the problem? Or is there anything one can do to configure Rails to make it work as is?

See [How to use unixODBC SSO connection to Snowflake with Rails using externalbrowser authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75457107/21217341) for the way the problem was identified.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/TalentBox/sequel-rails?

Comment: I would argue that the "right place" (its not one) is to do what sequel-rails, activerecord and mongoid all  do and add the ORM as a Railtie that plugs in into the hooks that Rails provides. If you look at sequel-rails it doesn't use the explicit connection configuration when defining the model classes which I doubt will play nice with Rails and Zeitwerk.

Comment: Also I think the issue here isn't actually due to the difference between operating systems. Instead its because classes are eager loaded in production at startup instead of autoloading on demand.

Comment: Tried your suggestion to directly `sequel-rails` (essentially removing the connect command and the explicit table references in the model definitions. Unfortunately it seems like `sequel-rails` and `sequel-snowflake` don't play together out of the box. At least I get a `LoadError: cannot load such file -- sequel/adapters/snowflake, (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)` error.

Comment: I have to admit I didn't change the environment, so eager_load is still false. The reason for using the explicit DB = Sequel.connect(... is that I'm connecting to an existing DB and all info online required to recreate the DB when connecting. Recreating the DB is not an option in this case.

Comment: I didn't really expected it to work out of the box - those are two pretty esoteric libraries you're plugging together.. But you can look at how they approached the problem and adapt it.

Comment: Seems `sequel-rails` doesn't actually work with odbc (and as such snowflake, as connection is happening through odbc interface.) So, it looks like I'm back to making the SAML authentication work on Linux.